# HTTP get request to a webservice. String is adding /u0000 at the end

Tags: ruby-on-rails

why is \u0000 being added multiple times to my string?

**Code:**

```
def getassetheader
    url = "https://api.dell.com/support/assetinfo/v4/getassetheader/" + params[:service_tag].to_s + "?apikey=MYAPIKEY                                  "
    uri = URI.parse(url)
    http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
    http.use_ssl = true

    request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
    response=http.request(request)
    byebug
  end
```

**byebug output:**

> (byebug) url
>   url
>   "https://api.dell.com/support/assetinfo/v4/getassetheader/GH3RV12?apikey=MYAPIKEY\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000"
>   (byebug) uri.request_uri
>   uri.request_uri "/support/assetinfo/v4/getassetheader/GH3RV12?apikey=MYAPIKEY%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00"
>   (byebug)

Comment: Have you tried opening your file in an editor that shows invisible characters, like notepad++?

Comment: It's even visible here...
`"https://api.dell.com/support/assetinfo/v4/getassetheader/" + params[:service_tag].to_s + "?apikey=MYAPIKEY                                  "`